# How to add a default email publisher to all projects in CruiseControl.NET?

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I've got multiple projects configured in CC.Net.

I'd like to use the email publisher for all of the projects,
Currently I've only managed to configure the email publisher per project and not globally.

Which means that If any of the project fails I'd like an e-mail dispatched.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, found this solution:

[CC.NET pre-processor](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Configuration+Preprocessor)

There is an example there for an external definition for an E-mail publisher.